# UNIX sockets vs AF_NETLINK vs Kdbus vs Binder

Tags: linux, d-bus, ipc, unix-sockets

What are essential differences between those IPCs? Which are main use cases?

Is there some consolidated comparison table between them somewhere? Something like:

```
Protocol:             AF_UNIX      | AF_NETLINK | Kdbus | Binder
-----------
Multicast features  | none
Security features   | SO_PEERCRED
Use cases           | 
client and          |
server samples      |
overhead            | 
standard compliance | POSIX
pros                | old&tested
cons                | no multicast
```